# Running certain ansible tasks only on certain processor vendors

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I want to configure IOMMU settings for a group of servers. Doing this requires making a change to grub configuration as such on Intel servers:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=on iommu=pt"
```

And like so on AMD servers:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amd_iommu=on iommu=pt"
```

I’ve tried the following:

```
---
- name: Configure GRUB for IOMMU based on CPU manufacturer
  hosts: your_target_hosts
  become: yes  # Necessary for permissions to edit GRUB config and update GRUB
  tasks:
    - name: Set GRUB options for Intel systems
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        path: /etc/default/grub
        regexp: '^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='
        line: 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=on iommu=pt"'
        backrefs: yes
      when: ansible_processor_vendor == 'GenuineIntel'
      notify: update-grub

    - name: Set GRUB options for AMD systems
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        path: /etc/default/grub
        regexp: '^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='
        line: 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amd_iommu=on iommu=pt"'
        backrefs: yes
      when: ansible_processor_vendor == 'AuthenticAMD'
      notify: update-grub

  handlers:
    - name: update-grub
      ansible.builtin.command:
        cmd: update-grub
```

When I run the playbook though, Ansible says that `ansible_processor_vendor` is undefined.

How can I actually construct this Playbook to accomplish my configuration change on each vendor as appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work! I had to use `when: ansible_processor[1] == 'GenuineIntel'`:

```
---
- name: Configure GRUB for IOMMU based on CPU manufacturer
  hosts: your_target_hosts
  become: yes  # Necessary for permissions to edit GRUB config and update GRUB
  tasks:
    - name: Set GRUB options for Intel systems
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        path: /etc/default/grub
        regexp: '^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='
        line: 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=on iommu=pt"'
        backrefs: yes
      when: ansible_processor[1] == 'GenuineIntel'
      notify: update-grub

    - name: Set GRUB options for AMD systems
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        path: /etc/default/grub
        regexp: '^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='
        line: 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amd_iommu=on iommu=pt"'
        backrefs: yes
      when: ansible_processor[1] == 'AuthenticAMD'
      notify: update-grub

  handlers:
    - name: update-grub
      ansible.builtin.command:
        cmd: update-grub
```

Comment: `when: "'GenuineIntel' in ansible_processor"`seems robuster.

Comment: I'm new to Ansible -- that does seem more robust, thank you!